# What's the price of the lockers in Tbilisi, Georgia main train station?

Tags: train-stations, tbilisi

How much do the lockers costs on a 24h basis?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes; if this gets closed I will vote on reopening. The close reason is given as "prices and availability change frequently in many locations" -- not for these. The price might go up very slightly but at any given train station one could very well expect to find only one left luggage service and at the same place year after year, heck, even decade after decade unless the whole place is renovated / rebuilt. We have tons of answers on the site which go out of date much quicker than the price / location of luggage lockers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately not likely the *current* price but may be of interest. [From Greg R on TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294195-i9344-k6710360-Coin_locker_or_left_luggage_in_tbilisi_anywhere-Tbilisi.html):

> **4. Re: Coin locker or left luggage in Tbilisi anywhere**
>   29 July 2013, 19:30
>
> Yes, the one in Tbilisi charges 4 lari per bag, for 24 hours I think.
>   I used it about a month ago. The station itself doesn't provide a left
>   luggage service, so this gap in the market is filled by a small
>   business. It's located on the first platform, further along the tracks
>   from the terminal building in a white portacabin. Although it looks
>   rather scruffy, it is well used and they're trustworthy; just don't
>   lose the ticket, because they speak no english at all. It's open 24-7,
>   and I think the family that runs it live there.
>
> If you're on the first platform and, for whatever reason, can't find
>   it. Ask one of the many people who will be hanging round there: Gdye
>   komnata dlya chimadana? if they don't speak english?

Answer (score 3):

There is one more new Luggage Storage in Tbilisi Center at Liberty Square #4 (next to Courtyard Marriott in arch).

It's more comfortable because it's self service and you can use it within 24 hours.

Hope it's helpful information for travelers!

https://smartcase.ge

Comment: Any specific price? Since that's the question.

Answer (score 2):

Smart Case is a first 24/7 self-service luggage lockers in Tbilisi.  location:

- Tbilisi, Liberty square, next to shopping mall Galleria Tbilisi and hotel Courtyard Marriott, In the arch. Box size: 49X28X70 CM Price From 5 GEL
- Tbilisi, 44 Kote Apkhazi, In the arch. Box size: 51X30X77 CM Price From 6 GEL . Box size 51X30X57 CM Price From 5 GEL

Comment: Please try to add a link to support your answer.